# Cant print to Wifi Printer in Lubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless, printing

I just updated to Lubuntu 15.04 and now I cannot print to my HP Wifi printer.  The printer shows up as a wifi network but I cannot connect to it.  It keeps asking for a password when the printer is not password protected.  The printer doesn't show up under system-Tools --> printer either.  All was working fine before the update.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, if printer is not shared, it does not show up in system-Tools --> printer

i filled this report

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-printer/+bug/1441423

it's still a mess for me, hope it helps you a little.